# node-config change delimiter from dot to colon

Tags: node-config

Im migrating my config from another library to [node-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config).

I have two questions:

1. The old library uses `config.get('a:b');` to get some value, but `node-config` use a single dot as a delimiter: `config.get('a.b');`.

Is there is a way to configure it to use `:` to save my time and refactor my code?

2. Is there is a way to set a runtime values. e.g. `config.set('key', 'val');`?

Answer (score 0):

Done it by:
1. wrap `node-config` in a new js file
2. proxied the `get`, `has` and `set` methods methods

Something like that:

```
const config = require('config');

const inMemDict = {};

const toNewKey = key => {
    return key && key.split(':').join('.');
};

const { get: origGet, has: origHas } = config;

config.get = function (key, ...args) {
    key = toNewKey(key);

    if(typeof inMemDict[key] !== 'undefined') {
        return inMemDict[key];
    }

    return origGet.apply(config, [key, ...args]);
};

config.has = function (key, ...args) {
    key = toNewKey(key);

    if(typeof inMemDict[key] !== 'undefined') {
        return inMemDict[key];
    }

    return origHas.apply(config, [key, ...args]);
};

config.set = function (key, val) {
    if(!key) return;
    inMemDict[toNewKey(key)] = val;
};

module.exports = config;
```